# QTableWidget with checkbox

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qcheckbox

I need to use `QTableWidget` with checkboxes instead of text in items. Checkbox must be in the center of item.

Examples which I tried work while checkbox is checked. If I uncheck checkbox it disapeares.

Comment: can you post here at least the source code of example where checkbox is disappearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the checkbox to be centered with this code:

```
   QWidget *pWidget = new QWidget();
   QCheckBox *pCheckBox = new QCheckBox();
   QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
   pLayout->addWidget(pCheckBox);
   pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
   pLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
   pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
   pMyTableWidget->setCellWidget(0,0,pWidget);
```

(I don't know if I understood you well here) And if you want to make your checkbox disappear when you uncheck it, you need to connect clicked signal of checkbox to a slot, that will make your checkbox invisible. Use connect method like this:

```
connect(checkbox,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(checkboxClicked()));
```

You need to create slot checkboxClicked where you will be checking if the checkbox is checked or not. If not then you have to set it invisible. Example:

```
  QCheckBox* Chb = qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(QObject::sender());
  if(!Chb->checked())
      Chb->setVisible(false);
```

Comment: +1 in real app it's still will be needed to implement custom QAbstractItemModel